# How does Gnome 3 execute commands that are bound to keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Can someone explain how GNOME 3 executes commands that are bound to keyboard shortcuts? I'm asking because all commands that I've bound execute only after double pressing.
I've checked it with:

1. modkey + <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `chromium`
2. modkey + <kbd>F2</kbd> -> `~/ownBashScript`

Here are my log's lines that are appended while I'm double-pressing modkey + <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
Windows manager warning: Log level 16: fetch_connections_done: error fetching connections: (25) Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1.
Windows manager warning: Log level 16: nm_client_get_devices: error getting devices: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

[Full log can be found here](http://www.pastie.org/3559744).